# Appium:WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj : Resources/WebDriverAgent.bundle: No such file or directory

Tags: appium-ios

When run `WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj` in `Xcode`, it displaying :

```
Showing All Messages
CpResource Resources/WebDriverAgent.bundle /Users/moitreyeec/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentLib.framework/WebDriverAgent.bundle
    cd /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Resources/WebDriverAgent.bundle /Users/moitreyeec/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentLib.framework
```

error:

> /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Resources/WebDriverAgent.bundle:
>   No such file or directory

I have searched that no such directory is present under `/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Hi this will help you https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent

Terminal - Go to the folder where the WebDriverAgent and run this command ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh

Answer (score -1):

This should be auto generated once you start appium and run a script. It's fine if there's error.

If not, try use `mkdir`